# How to sync a indexed db (in specific : Dexie) with Rest services?

Tags: javascript, database, dexie

```
db.syncable.connect ("websocket", "Rest Service URL");
```

Rest Service URL -your rest service url

```
db.syncable.on('statusChanged', function (newStatus, url) {
    console.log ("Sync Status changed: " + Dexie.Syncable.StatusTexts[newStatus]);
});
```

Sync on regular interval

The problem is the sync-able works only with the databases. Can anyone help me with reference/procedure on how this sync can be done on rest APIs with dexie.

Answer (score 1):

To sync with a REST API, that API will need to have sync-features, as for example Google Calendar API, where it is possible to provide a sync token to the REST API. [ISyncProtocol](http://dexie.org/docs/Syncable/Dexie.Syncable.ISyncProtocol.html) should be able to work against such an API, but I have no references of it yet. For docs about how to activate your implementation of the protocol, see [Dexie.Syncable tutorial](http://dexie.org/docs/Syncable/Dexie.Syncable.js#tutorial)

If you REST API will give you a sync token, the token can be passed as the lastRevision argument to [applyRemoteChanges](http://dexie.org/docs/Syncable/Dexie.Syncable.ISyncProtocol.html#applyremotechanges--function-changes-lastrevision-partial-clear). When the changes have been applied locally, the next call to your sync() function will provide the last sync token in the syncedRevision argument so that you can pass it to your REST API for further sync.